# How jhipster apps create databases on heroku platform?

Tags: mysql, heroku, jdbc, jhipster, cleardb

I am trying to deploy my app to heroku, the problem is that instead of creating the db with utf-8 as it is written in jdbc url:
url:
`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/devizionuseUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false`

It creates it with charset latin1. 
I tried connecting to the clear db remotely with ssl protocol using mysql workbench to change all tables charsets manually. But despite the fact that app works fine and able to save data, when i connect to db remotely my db has no tables in it.

I tried changing the initial schema file of liquibase to change default db encoding before tables are created like this:

```
    <changeSet id="0" author="jhipster">
            <sql>ALTER SCHEMA `devizion`  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;</sql>
    </changeSet>
```

But i get an error on startup: .

```
   Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Access denied for user 'be534518e17af9'@'%' to database 'devizion' [Failed SQL: ALTER SCHEMA `devizion`  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8]
```

Can anyone please explain me how to change the way jhipster creates db, and how can i change the default charset of them. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ask Heroku's support?